# Creating ubuntu boot disk in windows 10

Tags: boot

I downloaded the ubuntu .iso file in Windows 10.  How do I create either a bootable USB or dvd from here.

Comment: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0

Comment: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-burn-a-dvd-on-windows#0

Comment: OK.  Right clicked on the iso file.  I do not get the "Burn Disc image" option.

Comment: You can use **any** burning software for that. The answer below points to one of the possibilities but any will do as long as you know what to look for... "Burn image to disk", "ISO to disk". etc. are usual.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [windisk32](https://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/); Right click on the file, select open with windisk32, select the disk you want to write to, and it should work.